# How to launch a python shell with subprocess.run

Tags: python, shell

I have a function in my python script that needs to load a python shell.

```
run('python /my/script', shell=True)
```

The problem is that when I type something, the bash shell is providing output instead of the python shell.

Do you know why and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is far from a [mcve]... Could you build a minimal working example so that we can better understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `subrocess` Python module. If path of your Python executable is set as environment variable, you need to write only `python` when you call the another Python file, in other case you need the write the full path of your Python executable.

test.py Python file:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "other.py"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
print(std_out)
```

other.py Python file:

```
print("Hello from other Python file.")
```

output of test.py Python file:

```
>>>python test.py 
Hello from other Python file.
```